# image url with physical path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

In application I have physical path (OS path of image) and requirement is to assign this path to an image control. Image control imageUrl requires application path. Please advice how to do this.

THANKS

Comment: You can't (straightforwardly) display arbitrary files on your filesystem from ASP.NET. They have to be deployed as part of your app, or in some other web server.

Comment: what would be suggestion then ?

Comment: Deploy the image as part of your app, or in some other web server.

Comment: can adding the image as a resource help in this case..? if not I would suggest creating an Images folder on the web server as Millimoose has suggested

Comment: The alternative is using a regular `<img>` tag and pointing it at the URL of a custom controller or ASPX that will send the file using [`TransmitFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy.aspx), but this is both more complicated, and not really using the `Image` control. (Not like that control is necessary if you don't want to mess with it in postbacks, but still.) Also not ideal for caching.

Answer (score 0):

Like millimoose said, your file should be in the same folder or sub-folder of your deployed application. If but any chance they are (deployed with your app or copied manually) you could translate it to a relative path using something like this:

```
        string phicalPath = @"C:\WebSite\Images\myimg.png";
        String desiredRelativePath = phicalPath.Replace(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"], String.Empty);
```

Hope that helps.